# Store MySQL results in seperate PHP variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a MySQL query that returns 3 random rows whenever it is ran. I want to store each row in an array, with each column of the row a different part of the array. Hopefully Im being clear. Here is where Im at so far.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT NAME,AUTHOR,CITY FROM TESTIMONIALS ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

The problem with this is it stores EVERYTHING in $result, and I do not know how to reference different columns once it is there. I'm doing this so I can ultimately print the specified random entries that I would like into 9 different DIVs.

Comment: $result isn't the data from the query. it's simply a result handle. you don't get actual data until you do a fetch call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$array = Array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT NAME,AUTHOR,CITY FROM TESTIMONIALS ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: To expand a bit you would then be able to do the following echo $array['AUTHOR']; for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$row['COLUMNAME']` to get the column value.
Note that COLUMNAME will be case-sensitive.

For example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT NAME,AUTHOR,CITY FROM TESTIMONIALS ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $row['NAME'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Author: ' . $row['AUTHOR'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Also, read the big red notice on the [php.net manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):
**Use of this extension is discouraged.**
  Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using prepared statements as mysql_ is being deprecated. It is also susceptible to SQL injection if you are careless or inexperienced and don't escape your query strings properly.

Here is the solution using mysqli_:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database") or die(mysqli_error($link));
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
$query = 'SELECT NAME,AUTHOR,CITY FROM TESTIMONIALS ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3';
$arrTestimonials = array();   

if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $out_name, $out_author, $out_city);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        $arrTestimonials[]['name'] = $out_name;
        $arrTestimonials[]['author'] = $out_author;
        $arrTestimonials[]['city'] = $out_city;
    }
} // error preparing statement
```

The array will be structured as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 1
            [author] => Author 1
            [city] => City 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 2
            [author] => Author 2
            [city] => City 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 3
            [author] => Author 3
            [city] => City 3
        )

)
```