# Cannot print the results of MySQL query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have the following MySQL query

```
$jokerQuery = mysql_query("SELECT `Joker sport`,
        COUNT(`Joker sport`) AS jokerCount
        FROM Profiles
        WHERE `CompetitorID` = 5
        GROUP BY `Joker sport`
        ORDER BY COUNT(`Joker sport`) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ");
```

which returns the following result in phpMyAdmin

```
Joker sport | jokerCount
8           | 8
```

I thought the following php would display the result but it doesn't work. What should I write to echo the result?

```
$jokerResult = mysql_fetch_array($jokerQuery);
echo $jokerResult['Joker sport'];
echo $jokerResult['jokerCount'];
```

Comment: Have you connected to the database and to the correct table?

Comment: Thanks codingbiz and user1718294 - my code was correct but I'd put it in the wrong place. I'd have accepted your answer user1718294 if you hadn't deleted it.

Comment: mysql_ is being deprecated, stop using it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php See the big red box?

Comment: Thanks anditpainsme - why not provide the alternative code I can use in this example and I'll know for next time?

Comment: Hi John, if you're interested still interested you can have a look at one of my earlier answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773358/store-mysql-results-in-seperate-php-variables/12773484#12773484 or read the php documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, add `MYSQL_ASSOC` as the const in [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

```
$jokerResult = mysql_fetch_array($jokerQuery, MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo $jokerResult['Joker sport'];
echo $jokerResult['jokerCount'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
$jokerResult = mysql_fetch_array($jokerQuery, MYSQL_ASSOC);
print_r($jokerResult);
```

to see column names.